# In Python, changing a column type in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a .CSV file that I need to call using Python, and update a column type from general to a text column, then save with a new name (still in a .CSV format).

I've imported csv, os, and openpyxl (though it seems I may not need to use this any longer). I've opened the file directory, called the file using os but I can't figure out how to change the column type. Can anyone help? It seems .csv files are more tricky than working with Excel files.

```
import openpyxl
import csv
import os

os.chdir(r"placeholderfilelocation")
print("directory changed") 

os.startfile('testfile.csv')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read data from CSV file and transform from string to correct data-type, including a list-of-integer column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665628/read-data-from-csv-file-and-transform-from-string-to-correct-data-type-includin)

Comment: Hi Nene, welcome to StackOverflow! We would need some more information. Are you aware that a .csv file is a text file that is simply formatted a certain way? You can try to open that file in Notepad if you're on Windows to see how it looks like. Since this is a text file, all columns are text. Any Excel formatting is lost when saved as a .csv file. It's the reader application who is responsible to interpret a column to any type that would be appropriate.

Comment: CSV columns don't have *types*. CSV is a loosely-defined, text-based format for storing record-like data. What were you trying to accomplish with `os.startfile`?