# Is there a way to find and set the DataType from CSV file, without specifying it prior?

Tags: python, csv, parsing, types

I noticed an example by user647772 from [Reading Data from CSV file...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665628/read-data-from-csv-file-and-transform-from-string-to-correct-data-type-includin)

```
data = """True,foo,1,2.3,baz
False,bar,7,9.8,qux"""
reader = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(data), delimiter=",")
parsed = (({'True':True}.get(row[0], False),
       row[1],
       int(row[2]),
       float(row[3]),
       row[4])
      for row in reader)
 getBackData = list(parsed)
```

I couldn't find much for CSV Reader library related to code written for "parsed" variable. I'd really appreciate if somebody could point me to the correct documentation in python website.

Also, I am interested to know if there is a way I can determine the Data Type and set the value of variable parsed (above), at runtime. So, is the following implementation "valid" if I modify the code above like:

```
parsed = "((row[0], int(row[1]), int(row[2]), int(row[3]), row[4], row[5]) for row in rawReader)"
```

and

```
getBackData = list(eval((parsed)))
```

Or there is any better way?

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: First, I didn't do -1; it was someone else. Second, your question still isn't clear: given the `data` in the question, do you want - for each element in that list - to get the type of element it is?

Comment: @JackFleeting : have you read the question and, reference link, and even when i  reiterated - "I just want to read the CSV file, then identify and pick the feature/columns which are numeric types, so that I can perform required calculations". Never mind thanks for all your effort, dude !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `parsed` variable is not really special to `csv.reader` (there is no CSV Reader library, `csv` is a module in the Python std lib). This syntax is a Python `generator expression`. While this code *works*, compressing multiple concepts down into a single statement is not always the best when trying to illustrate a concept.

A more beginner-friendly form of this code might look like:

```
reader = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(data), delimiter=",")

# use a conventional for loop to build up the getBackData list
getBackData = []
for row in reader:
    converted_row = (
        row[0] == 'True',
        row[1],
        int(row[2]),
        float(row[3]),
        row[4],
        )
    getBackData.append(converted_row)
```

Even cleaner would be to push all those converters into a `convert_row` function, and then build up `getBackData` with a list comprehension:

```
def convert_row(raw):
    return (
        raw[0] == 'True',
        raw[1],
        int(raw[2]),
        float(raw[3]),
        raw[4],
        )

reader = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(data), delimiter=",")
getBackData = [convert_row(row) for row in reader]
```

Then you can modify the `convert_row` function however you like, but the `reader` and `getBackData` construction stay the same.

EDIT: getting the types (not very well tested, but this is the idea)

```
def try_bool(s):
    # will convert strings "True" and "False" to bools,
    # and raise an exception otherwise
    try:
        return {"True": True, "False": False}[s]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError("{!r} is not a valid bool".format(s))

def get_column_types(raw):
    types = []
    for col in raw:
        for test_type in (int, float, try_bool, str):
            try:
                test_type(col)
            except ValueError:
                # fail! not data of this type
                pass
            else:
                # it worked! add test_type to list of converters
                types.append(test_type)
                break
    return types

# read the first row and get the types of each column
first_row = next(csv.reader(input_file))
col_types = get_column_types(first_row)

# now create a list of new rows with converted data items
converted = []
for row in csv.reader(input_file):
    # use zip to walk list of converters and list of columns at the same time
    converted_row = [converter(raw_value)
                         for converter, raw_value in zip(col_types, row)]
    converted.append(converted_row)
```

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcG : I really appreciate the way you have unfolded that . Definitely putting multiple statements into one created a lot of confusion as I have started learning Python lately. Unable to upvote your reply because I dont have enough points on me.

Comment: Coming to the 2nd part of the query, the "eval(parsed)", is that recommended ? is it ok to use eval just like that, or there is any better way to do so ? The intent is to just read the CSV file at least 1st line, then identify the datatype in each feature/column, and pick the columns which are numeric types, so that I can perform required calculations. Eg: sort the data based on a numeric feature/column.

Comment: `eval()` won't work because you would like 'baz', 'qux', etc. to be read as strings, but they aren't enclosed in quotes. And in general, don't use `eval` for this kind of work, use `ast.literal_eval()` instead. But since you have non-numeric values mixed in, you'll need to explicitly try the various types for each column entry. Use csv.reader to get the first row, then go through each item trying to convert to int, then float, then bool, and then finally just leave it as str. Save these results off into a list of types, and then use that list to do all the conversions for all the rows.